# How to get the frequency( count) of Variable C when Variables A and B are mentioned together?

Tags: r, dplyr, frequency

I have the following dplyr code:

```
df3 <- Table3%>%
  group_by(Q6,Q9,Q11) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(per = paste0(round(100 *count/sum(count),2),'%')) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Q6 is a name, Q9 describes a topic that can be used for any value of Q6,  and Q11 is a Y/N (1/2) question if there is a goal mentioned.

I am not sure if my code is correct for the interpretation that i need because
i am not sure what summarize does, or counts when there are 3 variables. So i don't know what variable is the count.

```
summarise(count = n()) %>%
```

in short
I want to get a frequency and percent of how many times a goal was mentioned or not, every time Q6 and Q9 appeared together. I get this output but I am not sure if this is the correct frequency(count).

```
   Q6    Q9    Q11   count per   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr> 
 1 0     104   2         1 100%  
 2 0     105   2         1 100%  
 3 0     22    2         1 100%  
 4 0     25    2         1 100%  
 5 0     29    2         1 100%  
 6 0     30    2         1 100%  
 7 0     31    1         1 100%  
 8 0     42    1         1 100%  
 9 0     44    2         2 66.67%
10 0     44    NA        1 33.33%
11 0     5     1         1 100%  
12 0     51    NA        1 100%  
13 0     52    1         1 100%  
14 0     63    2         1 100%  
15 0     7     1         1 100%  
16 0     76    1         1 100%  
17 0     77    2         1 100%  
18 0     83    2         1 100%  
19 0     85    2         1 100%  
20 0     NA    NA        9 100%  
21 1     14    1         1 100%  
22 1     39    1         1 50%   
23 1     39    2         1 50%   
24 101   0     1         1 100%  
25 101   42    1         1 100%
```

this is a table of more than 500 rows, so I'd need to order them in decreasing order.
So for example in the table below,  line 2 would have to mean "When Q9(=44) was mentioned for Q6(=23), 8 times there was no goal mentioned (Q11=2) ."

lines 3,4 and 5 would be interpreted: "for Q6(=52), when topic 30 was mentioned in 8 instances there was also a goal mentioned, but when topic 89 was mentioned there was no goal in 7 instances, and in 6 instances when topic 29 was mentioned."

the percent throws me off, i am not sure how to interpret it, but i need to have it.

```
 Q6    Q9    Q11   count per   
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <chr> 
 1 0     NA    NA        9 100%  
 2 23    44    2         8 100%  
 3 52    30    1         8 61.54%
 4 52    89    2         7 100%  
 5 52    29    2         6 66.67%
 6 66    63    1         6 54.55%
 7 97    30    1         6 60%   
 8 52    30    2         5 38.46%
 9 60    42    2         5 55.56%
10 66    63    2         5 45.45%
11 19    51    2         4 80%   
12 19    7     1         4 66.67%
13 24    49    2         4 57.14%
14 52    99    2         4 100%  
15 53    41    2         4 100%  
16 60    105   2         4 80%   
17 60    42    1         4 44.44%
18 97    30    2         4 40%   
19 97    60    2         4 100%  
20 19    16    2         3 100%  
21 24    49    1         3 42.86%
22 272   7     1         3 100%  
23 5     46    2         3 100%  
24 52    29    1         3 33.33%
25 52    31    1         3 100%
```

is this correct? or does my count mean something else?

would really appreciate help with the interpretation, or a better code for what i am looking for?

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish from this question, but `summarise(count = n())` will return the number of unique Q6, Q9, Q11 combinations as these were the grouping variables in `group_by`. Line 2 `count` means there were 8 rows that had Q6 = 23, Q9 = 44, and Q11 = 2. `Summarise` drops the last grouping variable, so your percent is showing you the percent of each count based on groups defined by Q6 and Q9 (compare lines 9 and 17).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n()` returns you the number of cases of that particular combination in `group_by`. As you showed two different outputs, I'm not sure exactly how you got them, and so, not sure how to interpret your %s.

Without a reproducible example, it's hard to help you fully. But if I got it right, you're on the right track. I'd just be careful with counting inside different group settings.

There is definitely a more cleaver way of doing it, but I'd break it down in two steps, as in the code below, to not mess with different count numbers given different grouping variables

```
library(dplyr)

## Crete some fake data
set.seed(101)

df <- 
  data.frame("Q6" = sample(8:10, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
             "Q9" = round(rnorm(n = 50, mean = 32, sd = 2), digits = 0),
             "Q11" = sample(1:2, size = 50, replace = TRUE))

## Then summarise the number of occurrences
## based on combinations of Q6 and Q9
## i.e. how many times that combination of Q6 and Q9 happened 

out1 <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(Q6, Q9) %>%
  summarise(n_q6_q9 = n())

## Then count the number of Y/N (your Q11) by combinations of Q6 and Q9
## i.e. how many Y or N for each Q6~Q9 combination

out2 <- 
  df %>%
  group_by(Q6, Q9, Q11) %>%
  summarise(n_q11 = n())

## Merge them and calculate the percentage

out_final <- 
  left_join(out2, out1, by = c("Q6", "Q9")) %>%  ## Note order of out2 and out1
  mutate(per = paste0(round(n_q11/n_q6_q9 * 100, digits = 2), "%")) 
  # %>% ## Not sure if you need to arrange it?
  # group_by(Q6, Q9) %>%
  # arrange(per)
```